# KX developer installation port setting error for Q/Kdb+

Tags: kdb

```
    KDB+ 4.0 2020.05.04 Copyright (C) 1993-2020 Kx Systems 
    l64/ 8(16)core 7843MB n3 n3-n550jk 127.0.1.1 EXPIRE 2022.02.11 nikhil.exec@gmail.com KOD #4174xyz
    
    [developer] version 1.4.3
    [developer] loading...
    [developer] setting q port to localhost:port
    [developer] failed to start Kx Developer: error setting port 
    q)
```

I have updated bashrc and conig file as mentioned in https://code.kx.com/developer/known-issues/
still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use kx developer but port should be an available port number e.g. `localhost:12345` not the word `port`